# How can I prevent javascript caching? Querystring approach isn't working

Tags: javascript, caching

I've seen other approaches that attach a version number or MD5 hash to a JS src querystring.

```
e.g. <script src='/script/v1/'></script>
```

However, my JavaScript is *still* getting cached in multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox) when I push a new version of my site.

This seems like a major problem that others have solved, and I seem to be doing the right things. How can I get this to work?

Comment: What server do you have?

Comment: These static files are served from lighttpd

Comment: Then I fear the files are cached in the server memory.. here is something that led me in this direction: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModMemCache

Comment: Anyone knows if query string appending is reliable? i.e. /script.js?v=1.1    I usually use here /script_timestamp.js  but would prefer the querystring approach (looks cleaner to me).

Comment: @flaviotsf - look at my answer below, specifically the reference to Steve Souders' blog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added log messages and determined that the querystring method *is* working. Sorry for the unnecessary question.

**However**, in researching, I found some important points worth mentioning:

1. One of the articles suggests using a querystring with the current time appended. You probably don't want to follow this suggestion as your files will *never* be cached. Using source control version numbers or an MD5 hash would be better.
2. Steve Souders (of [High Performance Web Sites](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529309) fame) notes that certain web proxies never cache anything with a querystring. Thus, the version number should be embedded within the path to the file in order to ensure that your files are cached appropriately when accessed through these proxies. ( http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/ )

Answer (score 1):

It will be cached always. Although, by using a version number (or any other varying string) a new version will be downloaded and used every time, ignoring the previous one.

http://thecrmgrid.wordpress.com/2007/10/22/prevent-caching-of-javascript-include-files-during-development/

http://davidwalsh.name/prevent-cache

Comment: That's what I'm saying -- I do that and it's not working. Everyone in my company experiences this frequently, and I swear we're not dumbasses. Hence my question and confusion.

Comment: That's the expected behavior. Still, by appending ?something to the file name, you will force a new version to be downloaded (and cached), avoid the browsers cache.

Answer (score 0):

1.)make sure the response headers for the javascript files are correct and include expires, cache-control, etc.

2.)you probably have to append the version not as a query parameter but part of the filename, e.g. page_v.2.js. You could change the javascript filenames at build time for example if you are using Java. That is what i have done.

Comment: Edited my question to show that that's actually what we do -- it's not a querystring parameter, it's a unique URL based on the MD5 hash.

Comment: Will check the expires & cache-control settings.